# In Puppet deployment, do all agent nodes have to be connected to an Internet repository?

Tags: puppet, repository

Or does the master cache the repository from the internet and provision for the agent nodes?

In either case, how are updates deployed and managed?
What pre-empts what?

Edit: How are rpm updates, yum updates, tarball updates, zypper updates, apt-get updates etc.. deployed/managed/supervised.

Comment: Updates of what?

Comment: The master doesn't cache OS package repositories, it just runs the `yum`/`apt`, etc command to ensure what you told it to ensure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How are rpm updates, yum updates, tarball updates, zypper updates, apt-get updates etc.. deployed/managed/supervised.

There is no default configuration for this.  You define it yourself.

For my Debian systems I use puppet to update the apt sources lists on my nodes that point at an [approx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approx) instance (apt proxy/cache) that just happens to run on my puppet host.  If I didn't do that, the machines would just go out using whatever apt sources were defined at install time.

Just as easily you could download things on your puppet master and deliver them to your nodes via `file{}` resources.  It is all up to you.  Nothing auto-magical takes place here.  You define the behavior you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying. You answered my question.

Comment: @Mugambo if this answered your question, you should mark it as the accepted answer.